# Custom post type specific category box

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

Is it possible to give a custom post type its own category box?

If I use `'taxonomies' => array("category")` or `register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', post_type);` I get the desired box but it shows all categories across all post types.

[image]

I want the displayed values in the meta box to show just that post types categories.

If I use:

```
register_taxonomy( 'categories',
    array (
        0 => 'event',
    ),
    array( 
        'hierarchical' => false, 
        'label' => 'Event Categories',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => ''),
        'singular_label' => 'Event Category'
    ) 
);
```

then I have to manually type tags opposed to being able to click a checkbox to assign categories.

[image]

This breaks the UX for less computer savvy people.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I answered based on a "must be" supposition. To improve your Question you should put *all* the code you are using, i.e.: "(... etc)" is not meaningful.

Comment: Added the full code for `register_taxonomy` for archival purposes. Added pictures to help further illustrate the actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) (as you have) except change the `hierarchical` argument to `true` for the meta box to behave like the default categories taxonomy:

```
'hierarchical' => true
```

Comment: Ahh. Most excellent. Just what I was looking for! Thank you.